# Recover Skype image from HEX

Tags: data-recovery, skype

I'd like to recover a lost image from my own Skype's `main.db`. The images are encoded as HEX. Do you know how to turn them back into the original format?

They go like that:

> 0x00FFD8FFE000...

What function might they use?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer pretty quickly so here's the C# solution for referece:

```
void Main()
{
    var data ="00FFD8FFE000...";    
    var original = Convert.FromHexString(data);
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\image.jpg", original); 
}
```

It's important to trim the `0x` at the beginning.